# Connect with SSH tunnel to MongoDB in Azure Container instance under VNET

Tags: mongodb, azure-container-instances, vnet

I have MongoDB deployed to Azure Container Instance. Now, I want to secure my DB by moving it under Virtual Net. How can I connect to MongoDB using SSH tunnel?

Comment: If you want to secure your database, MongoDB supports TLS and X.509 authentication natively. If you want to use an SSH tunnel, you could maybe do so with a split horizon setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running ACI in a private VNET/Subnet, the easiest way to access your service would be to create VM in the same VNET/Subnet and log into that VM

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#deploy-to-existing-virtual-network

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot, just what i needed. The only thing is that ACI and VM needs to be in different subnets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-virtual-network-concepts